Next.js Features Dependent on Vercel Infrastructure
I've noticed that some Next.js features don't work properly when you move your project outside of Vercel. Features like Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR), edge functions, and advanced caching strategies seem to be tightly integrated with Vercel's infrastructure. While it's technically possible to replicate these outside of Vercel, it requires significant effort.
Similarly, preview modes and analytics seem to work seamlessly only within the Vercel ecosystem.
Has anyone successfully replicated these features on other platforms, or is it just more efficient to stick with Vercel for projects that require this level of functionality? What are the trade-offs or challenges you've encountered when migrating these features elsewhere?

We use a self-hosted version of Next.js with the standalone output and don't experience any limitations with using ISR.
Regarding other aspects, I suggest looking into OpenNext. They focus on decoupling existing features from Vercel's vendor lock-in and provide instructions on deploying Next.js on AWS/Cloudflare independently. However, I haven't looked into the limitations in detail, and you should keep in mind that they might not support all Next.js features, considering the frequent releases.
